# How start 2 containers docker at the same time

Tags: docker

I start now study Docker and I need start 2 containers in Docker at the same time, the container has already been created: container_1 and container_2. How can I use the command **docker start container_1** and **docker start container_2** at the same time?

Comment: Using `docker start` is a little bit unusual; in typical use you'd just `docker run` a container, or use a tool like Docker Compose to manage multiple containers together.  Can you give a more complete example of what you're trying to do and what trouble you're running into?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple containers in `docker start`.

```
docker start container_1 container_2
```

They won't start at exactly the same time, but they'll start closely after eachother.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to explain why you’re trying to do this. My best guess is that you’re trying to plumb together these containers, so you should consider using a coordination mechanism such as docker-compose or kubernetes to automatically manage the coordination for you.

Comment: I am not  trying to plumb together these containers, i only wants to know how run 2 containers at the same time, the containers are
independent

Comment: Then just start them with separate `docker start` or `docker run` commands. I don’t believe the `docker` command has syntax to start multiple containers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

u need to write a docker-compose file , without using links or depends as those two containers are independent..then> sudo docker compose up wil start running those containers for u ..